# How to Handle Country Specific URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I would like to make changes in my exiting project as I need to make it expand to more countries.

As different country will see different views (blade templates).

I need best approach to make URL SEO Friendly.

After searching I found few options out of them I need to do this.

I need to change my website URL according to visitor destination.

I need to change from

```
www.domain.com
```

to

```
www.domain.com/{country}

For Example: 
www.domain.com/in
www.domain.com/ca
www.domain.com/us
```

I have tons of routes. I am looking for a solution!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206015/fastest-way-of-detecting-users-country

Comment: Did you check prefixes for routing?